# Why is it not allowed add toString() to interface as default method?

Tags: java

Why does Java 8 not allow to add a default implementation for toString() in an interface?

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    @Override
    default String toString(){
        return "";
    }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
Error:(8, 20) java: default method toString in interface task1_3.
SomeInterface overrides a member of java.lang.Object
```

Comment: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-March/008435.html

Comment: @MarounMaroun Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is done to avoid problems with multiple inheritance.

The general rule is that an object cannot inherit two implementations of a single method. This rule applies in several situations - for example, when you try implementing two interfaces, both having the same method with default implementations:

```
interface Animal {
    default void saySomething() {
        System.out.println("Something");
    }
}

interface Cat {
    default void saySomething() {
        System.out.println("Meow");
    }
}

class Tiger implements Animal, Cat {
    // Restricted
}
```

You must override `saySomething()` in the `Tiger` class above; otherwise the class will not compile.

Similarly, when you provide a default implementation of the `java.lang.Object`'s `toString` method in an interface, you are introducing an ambiguity, because any class implementing your interface would also inherit from `Object` one way or the other, so the compiler would need to decide between two implementations (despite the fact that you are trying to tell the compiler through the `@override` attribute that you want your default implementation to win). In order to resolve this ambiguity, the compiler would require all classes that implement `SomeInterface` to override `toString` as well. However, this means that the default implementation would never be used. Hence, the language prohibits supplying it in the first place.